# Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my code snippet

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="dtataOne in dataOnes()">
      <tr>
          <td>My Data</td>
          <td class="task-container ui-sortable" colspan="6" ng-model="dtataOne.MyModel" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" stafflastname="{{'Pup-Only'}}" data2="{{'999999'}}" task="{{100}}" data3="{{'No'}}">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"  ng-repeat="tg in Getdata(data3)" ng-click="ShowData(tg)">{{tg.count}}</a>
          </td> 
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Controller :

```
  $scope.Getdata = function(data3) {
        var datas = [];       
            data3.forEach(function (staff) {
                if (true) {
                    staff.tgs.forEach(function (tg) {
                        datas.push(tg);
                    });
                } 
        });

        $scope.data3s().forEach(function (datum) {
            if (datum.id === data3.id) {
                datum.MyModel = datas;
            }
        });
        return datas;
    };
```

In the above code snippet in the line " datum.MyModel = datas;" I am getting an error message like the one mentioned below

Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%

Any help will be life saving ....

Answer (score 2):

On every digest cycle the function `Getdata(data3)` will get fired. In that function you are mutating `datum.MyModel` which kick off an new digest cycle. If this repeats more then 10 times, you get an error.

The short advice: don’t use functions in an `ngRepeat` expression.