# Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] and replaceState history error angular js state management in routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#angular-routing), and I'm in the angular routing part. [Here is the code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/fEbgM/149/). It runs properly in the jsFiddle as well as the local system. But gives error in the console.

In case the jsfiddle link does not work, here is the code:

`app.js`

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
    }])
.factory(
    'posts', [function(){
        var o = {
            posts: []
        };
        return o;
    }]
    )
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'posts',
    function($scope, posts){
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;
        $scope.test = 'Hello World';

        $scope.posts = [
        {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
        {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
        {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
        {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
        {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
        ];


        $scope.addPost = function(){
            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title, 
                upvotes: 0,
                link: $scope.link,
            });
            $scope.link = '';
            $scope.title = '';
        };

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };

    }
    ]);
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.17/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts| orderBy: '-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span> {{post.upvotes}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
    {{post.title}}
    </a>
    <span ng-hide="post.link">
    {{post.title}}
    </span>  
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new post</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error that I get in the console is huge, one being - `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]`

and the other one is `Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'path/to/index.html#/home' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'`

As done by [someone here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907428/uncaught-error-rootscopeinfdig), I'm not calling any function in the ng-repeat as well. Please help.