# Angular JS Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with my angular chat applcation. I keep getting the error in the title of this question. Anybody have an idea what could be causing this? It's happening every time I type something in the textarea. The error is generated twice for every character input and I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. Even when the function is empty it still generates that annoying error.

```html
<textarea placeholder="Type a message" ng-keyup="::chatWith(this, <?php echo $data['sender']; ?>)" class="chat-window-input"></textarea>
```

```js
$scope.chatWith = function($event, recepient){
    
    var e = event.target;
    
    $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
    
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
     
        var msg = {sender:$scope.sender_id,recepient:recepient,message:$(e).val().trim()};
     
        $scope.socket.emit('cmd', {type:'MSG', MSG:msg});
        $(e).val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: \[$rootScope:infdig\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907428/uncaught-error-rootscopeinfdig)

Comment: var e = event.target; ===>     var e = $event.target;